# Apache mod_status, full machne readable details

Tags: apache-2.4, monitoring, apache2

[Apache's `mod_status`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) (i.e `/server-status`) outputs HTML, including what HTTP clients are accessing what thing right now. There is a text format (`/server-status?auto`), but that doesn't include the current HTTP clients.

Is there anyway to get all the data that's on a regular mod_status display, but in a much more machine parseable format? (Or do I need to parse the HTML)?

Apache v2.4.52
Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS

Comment: Did you try with set `ExtendedStatus  on`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `ExtendedStatus On`